# How to fetch data from firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to show all data into Recycleview but only  first image load other are not
shown recycleviewList anybody have idea about this.

[image]

```
         mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    // get reference to 'users' node
    mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("items");

    mFirebaseDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String getImage= (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            String ConvertImage;
            ConvertImage = getImage.replaceAll("\\[", 
            "").replaceAll("\\]","");
            String[] items = ConvertImage.split(",");

            List<String> list = Arrays.asList(items);
            Log.e("list",list.toString());

            for (String item : list) {
                arraylist.add(item);
                setImg(arraylist);
            }


     }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all those link, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference itemsRef = rootRef.child("items");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String link = ds.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", link);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
itemsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The output will contain, all those links from your `item` node.

Comment: Give me more details, I cannot help you, if you don't provide me details regarding your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to retrieve all the links and still only one image loads, then check the xml layout of single list item of RecyclerView and make sure the height is wrap_content and NOT match_parent like this

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: did you try Alex answer? were you able to see the links in Logcat??

Comment: what is this line `Log.d("TAG", link);` printing in Logcat? and make sure you are using this path `DatabaseReference itemsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("items");`